# WS Binding in Silverlight 4

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, ws-security

Will Silverlight 4.0 Support more Bindings for WCF e.g. WS-Binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SL4 will support the netTcp binding in addition to basicHttp and webHttp (REST).

See :

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/WCF-NET.TCP-Protocol-in-Silverlight-4.aspx

Comment: Reading the article its says "Net.tcp binding support in Silverlight 4 beta is one of the most important new features. It brings us excellent performance but with some security constraints such us port limitations. Because of that it is recommended to use it for Intranet applications in secure environments where you can control firewall settings."

But is strikes me that if silverlight is going to be used for mobile apps then this is a bit of a nonsense. Is this basically saying there is no secure way to speak to a WCF service?

Comment: @AJM: netTcp works great in Intranet scenarios. Not recommended for Internet apps. There is no secure way for **Silverlight apps** to talk to WCF - it's **not** a deficiency of WCF per se - but a limitation of the Silverlight implementation